# Unhandled exceptions from DropBox API in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, dropbox

I am trying to implement DropBox in my android app following instructions as given [here](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-java/blob/master/ReadMe.md#setup) . (using gradle)

When I get to the line: `FullAccount account = client.users().getCurrentAccount();` I recieve the error

> Unhandled exceptions: com.dropbox.core.DbxApiException, com.dropbox.core.DbxException

from the `getCurrentAccount()` part.
I can follow the suggestion to 'surround with try/catch' but if I do this the app crashes upon loading.

Apologies in advance for my ignorance. I am learning as I go along.

UPDATE:

I have realised I do not have the `throws DbxException` in  my code. Trying the place it after `onCreate` method gives the error

> 'onCreate(Bundle)' in 'com.example.MyApp.MainActivity' clashes with 'onCreate(Bundle)' in 'androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity'; overridden method does not throw 'com.dropbox.core.DbxApiException'

LOGCAT DATA:

```
2020-07-30 17:53:50.011 10050-10050/com.example.stockscan_alpha3 E/TypefaceCompatApi26Impl: Unable to collect necessary methods for class java.lang.NoSuchMethodException
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: android.graphics.FontFamily.<init> []
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2332)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1728)
    at androidx.core.graphics.TypefaceCompatApi26Impl.obtainFontFamilyCtor(TypefaceCompatApi26Impl.java:321)
    at androidx.core.graphics.TypefaceCompatApi26Impl.<init>(TypefaceCompatApi26Impl.java:84)
    at androidx.core.graphics.TypefaceCompatApi28Impl.<init>(TypefaceCompatApi28Impl.java:36)
    at androidx.core.graphics.TypefaceCompat.<clinit>(TypefaceCompat.java:47)
    at androidx.core.graphics.TypefaceCompat.create(TypefaceCompat.java:190)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.setTypeface(AppCompatTextView.java:705)
    at android.widget.TextView.resolveStyleAndSetTypeface(TextView.java:2183)
    at android.widget.TextView.setTypefaceFromAttrs(TextView.java:2154)
    at android.widget.TextView.applyTextAppearance(TextView.java:4105)
    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:1630)
    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:990)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:99)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:95)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createTextView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:182)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:103)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1407)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1457)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:1059)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:995)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:959)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1121)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:680)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:532)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
    at com.example.stockscan_alpha3.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:48)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7995)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7979)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)

2020-07-30 17:53:50.149 10050-10050/com.example.stockscan_alpha3 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.stockscan_alpha3, PID: 10050
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.stockscan_alpha3/com.example.stockscan_alpha3.MainActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
 Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1600)
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:115)
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:103)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1152)
    at com.android.okhttp.Dns$1.lookup(Dns.java:41)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:178)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:144)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:86)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:176)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:128)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:97)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:289)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:465)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:131)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:262)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getOutputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:219)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:30)
    at com.dropbox.core.http.StandardHttpRequestor.getOutputStream(StandardHttpRequestor.java:132)
    at com.dropbox.core.http.StandardHttpRequestor.access$000(StandardHttpRequestor.java:29)
    at com.dropbox.core.http.StandardHttpRequestor$Uploader.<init>(StandardHttpRequestor.java:141)
    at com.dropbox.core.http.StandardHttpRequestor.startPost(StandardHttpRequestor.java:73)
    at com.dropbox.core.http.StandardHttpRequestor.startPost(StandardHttpRequestor.java:29)
    at com.dropbox.core.DbxRequestUtil.startPostRaw(DbxRequestUtil.java:276)
    at com.dropbox.core.v2.DbxRawClientV2$1.execute(DbxRawClientV2.java:146)
    at com.dropbox.core.v2.DbxRawClientV2.executeRetriable(DbxRawClientV2.java:330)
    at com.dropbox.core.v2.DbxRawClientV2.executeRetriableWithRefresh(DbxRawClientV2.java:351)
    at com.dropbox.core.v2.DbxRawClientV2.rpcStyle(DbxRawClientV2.java:137)
    at com.dropbox.core.v2.users.DbxUserUsersRequests.getCurrentAccount(DbxUserUsersRequests.java:161)
    at com.example.stockscan_alpha3.MainActivity.testDropBox(MainActivity.java:138)
    at com.example.stockscan_alpha3.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:79)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7995)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7979)
```

Comment: Please show the full exception log.

Answer (score 0):

You may be getting this error because it is a network call and you need to implement some kind of callback. Looking at the Dropbox SDK you will need something like this:

```
    new GetCurrentAccountTask(DropboxClientFactory.getClient(), new GetCurrentAccountTask.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(FullAccount result) {
          // handle logic 
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Exception e) {
            Log.e(getClass().getName(), "Failed to get account details.", e);
        }
    }).execute();
```